# Why am I getting different validation between an XSD regex with Nokogiri and normal Ruby regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex, xsd, nokogiri

I have an XSD schema that includes a rule for a specific field to match the following regex:

```
\d{8}[\-]?[A-Za-z]{0,3}
```

Using irb, I can test with this regex and the following strings all match, which is correct:

```
12345678
12345678-
12345678-abc
12345678abc
```

When I attempt to validate some XML against this XSD, I get slightly different behaviour:

```
Passes:
12345678-
12345678-abc
12345678abc

Fails:
12345678
```

And here is a mimimal XSD/XML files that reproduces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:simpleType name="codeType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
   <xs:pattern value="\d{8}[\-]?[A-Za-z]{0,3}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
 <xs:element name="test">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="codeType" name="code"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <code>11034755</code>
</test>
```

And running this with

```
xmllint --schema test.xsd test.xml
```

Gives

```
Element 'code': [facet 'pattern'] The value '11034755' is not accepted by the pattern '\d{8}[\-]?[A-Za-z]{0,3}'
```

While XML schema does not have full regular expressions, this should be valid I think. What am I not understanding when it comes to regular expressions in XSD files in this particular case with regards to '?' ?

Comment: Since you didn't give us the XML you're validating against, we can't give you a solid answer. It's important to remember to do give us code, sample data, expected output, real output and a good explanation. The better you do supplying that, the better we can do giving you help. Remember: GIGO.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rubular to test [`/\d{8}-?(?:[a-zA-Z]{3})?/`](http://rubular.com/r/QQq6dRFBco) I get hits for all strings.

Alternately [`/\d{8}[a-zA-Z-]*/`](http://rubular.com/r/FbE3wmMfqr), [`/\d{8}[a-z-]*/i`](http://rubular.com/r/Or6yG812tW), and [`/\d{8}[a-z-]{0,4}/i`](http://rubular.com/r/eQ4bO2xdcz) work also.

You can use `{0,3}` or `{,3}` so those might help.

Comment: /\d{8}-{0,1}[A-Za-z]{0,3}/ also does it. It appears that '?' doesn't work the way I quite expect it to in XML Schemas.